# Shaping a tic tac toe in python

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, graphical-programming

I'm new to this forum, so I don't really know the rules and the submission template here. sorry if i do some mistakes.

So my problem is that I have a code that makes 2 AI play Tic Tac Toe. Here is the output of the game.

| X | O | X |

| X | O | X |

| O | O | X |

And I need to present this to an audience and would like to present my output in a more graphical version like this:

[Tic Tac Toe graphical version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNc90.png)

So my question is, how do I turn my output into my graphical version?

Thanks to help me

Comment: Is your program purely console right now?

Comment: If you have time, you can install `tkinter` library, with that you can make a window and [draw shapes](https://zetcode.com/tkinter/drawing/) in here (you can even make it interactive, but it may be overwhelming, so atleast do the drawing)

Comment: Use kivy module and canvas, on pick put a picture into an empty spot or use tkinter module or pygame module

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov sure, but i can even put it in a notepad

Comment: @MichałMazur Ok, i take a look, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to give a look at some GUI libraries like Qt, Kivy, pygame...
I find `tkinter` to be one of the easiest to work with, [here's](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-code-tic-tac-toe-in-python-using-tkinter-e7f9ce510bfb) a tutorial about tic-tac-toe specifically.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
count=0
board=[[‘’,’’,’’,],
 [‘’,’’,’’,],
 [‘’,’’,’’,]]

def TicTacToeGUI():
    global t
    t=Tk()
    t.title("TIC TAC TOE")
    t.configure(bg="white")  
    #Making the background of the window as white#Displaying the player
    l1=Label(t,text="PLAYER: 1(X)",height=3,font=("COMIC SANS MS",10,"bold"),bg="white")
    l1.grid(row=0,column=0)#Quit button
    exitButton=Button(t,text="Quit",command=Quit,font=("COMIC SANS MS",10,"bold"))
    exitButton.grid(row=0,column=2)#Grid buttons
    b1=Button(t,text="",height=4,width=8,bg="black",activebackground="white",fg="white",font="Times 15 bold",command=lambda: changeVal(b1,0,0))
    b2=Button(t,text="",height=4,width=8,bg="black",activebackground="white",fg="white",font="Times 15 bold",command=lambda: changeVal(b2,0,1))
    b3=Button(t,text="",height=4,width=8,bg="black",activebackground="white",fg="white",font="Times 15 bold",command=lambda: changeVal(b3,0,2))
    b4=Button(t,text="",height=4,width=8,bg="black",activebackground="white",fg="white",font="Times 15 bold",command=lambda: changeVal(b4,1,0))
    b5=Button(t,text="",height=4,width=8,bg="black",activebackground="white",fg="white",font="Times 15 bold",command=lambda: changeVal(b5,1,1))
    b6=Button(t,text="",height=4,width=8,bg="black",activebackground="white",fg="white",font="Times 15 bold",command=lambda: changeVal(b6,1,2))
    b7=Button(t,text="",height=4,width=8,bg="black",activebackground="white",fg="white",font="Times 15 bold",command=lambda: changeVal(b7,2,0))
    b8=Button(t,text="",height=4,width=8,bg="black",activebackground="white",fg="white",font="Times 15 bold",command=lambda: changeVal(b8,2,1))
    b9=Button(t,text="",height=4,width=8,bg="black",activebackground="white",fg="white",font="Times 15 bold",command=lambda: changeVal(b9,2,2))
    b1.grid(row=2,column=0)
    b2.grid(row=2,column=1)
    b3.grid(row=2,column=2)b4.grid(row=3,column=0)
    b5.grid(row=3,column=1)
    b6.grid(row=3,column=2)b7.grid(row=4,column=0)
    b8.grid(row=4,column=1)
    b9.grid(row=4,column=2)
```